# My joomla sending spam text mail

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

When I submit a contact form my joomla sends spam text content, how can I fix it? I searched the whole code for that message and I can not find that text, maybe he will be using text from some curl or some different way.

Can you please guide to which file to see to debug or to solve this issue.
Or any other way to fix it out

It is joomla 3.4

Comment: why -1 may i know reason

Comment: The mail from contact form is sent here: /components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php. You can try to look for differences against the original joomla file or you can follow the code until you find something strange.

Comment: this file seems fine

Comment: is there any way i can update conatct extenstion only ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you from email domain matches the domain name it is being sent from. Otherwise it has a high chance of being flagged as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Please *set* your **'from'(sender) and 'to'(receiver)**, specified. If these 2 values are not specified then mail are received in spam only.

I hope you are using **Joomla Mail Function** only for this.